# Less - How to jump to a part in a large pdf?

Tags: linux, less

I am using `less` to view a large (Think over 5k page) pdf in my terminal. The pdf is divided up into chapters. I am curious to know, how do I go to a certain chapter in the pdf without knowing the line number? I tried searching the `man` pages, but I was unable to ascertain what I needed to know.

I don't want to scroll down for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`less` views *text files* (likely you're using a filter via `lessopen.sh`).  Within *text files*, `less` lets you search for *regular expressions*, like `vi`.  If your chapter headers matched a pattern like

```
Chapter 123. This is a Title
```

then you could type

```
/chapter [0-9]+\.[[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]]
```

and `less` would search for that.

(Whether to ignore the difference between uppercase and lowercase is an option **`-i`**: it helps to read the manual page).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
less -GN -p "Chapter N"
```

The -p parameter search for text using regex and moves it to the beginning of the screen.